# Is it possible to use a src of icons with external path inside manifest.json (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, manifest

So the structures are like this, assuming we have two projects- project1 and project2, and each of them has its own manifest.json, and its own assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png.

```
-project2
 |_src
 |   |_assets
 |   |   |_icons
 |   |      |_apple-touch-icon-144x144.png
 |   |_manifest.json
 |   |_index.html
-project1
 |_src
 |   |_assets
 |   |   |_icons
 |   |      |_apple-touch-icon-144x144.png
 |   |_manifest.json
 |   |_index.html
-assets_outside
  |_icons_outside
    |_ apple-touch-icon-144x144.png
```

Therefore, inside the manifest.json, normally, it should be written like this:

```
...
"name": "project1",
"scope": "/",
"start_url": "/",
"icons":[
 {
   "src":"assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png",    <===== notice here
   "sizes":"144*144",
   "type":"image/pmg" 
 },
  ...
]
...
```

and inside index.html

```
    <link href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png"
        rel="apple-touch-icon"
        sizes="144x144">
```

The above code shows the **`project1`** is using the pictures inside its own assets/icon,

**My question is:**

If both projects are using the same icons and pictures,

Would it be possible to use the picture outside the project folder?

I am not sure, but maybe also inside the angular.json file also need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest you to use symlink to outside_assets in the each and stick to an absolute paths in manifest files.